# I have muliple webforms in my site, but want to disable all webforms after user makes a submission

Tags: users, webforms

I'm stuck. I have a site that has many users. Each user is allowed to log in and has access to a certain number of webforms (depending on their role status). Each webform contains a product that they receive for yearly award. They can pick from any of the products/forms that their user role allows.

The problem lies when they submit the form/product that they would like, the other forms are still active, which would allow them to submit another form etc etc.

I need to deactivate ALL webforms for that user when they submit their form/product choice so they cannot submit multiple products from the same user.

Please help.

B

Answer (score 0):

make a user role `user has submitted survey`. use `hook_webform_submission_insert` or `hook_webform_submission_update` (what you use depends on if you allow Drafts) -- and change whatever role they have by default in your site, to `user has submitted survey`. Dont allow this new role to access any forms.